# Convert int array into a bunch of ints

Tags: java

I have

```
public int average(int grades[]){return **}
```

and I call it with: average({80, 90, 100})

I want to separate the array into three individual ints.

Comment: Why you need to do this? By the way you can get individual int like this - `avarage[0]`, `avarage[1]`, `avarage[2]`

Comment: @Razib That might be all I need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public int average1 = average[0];
public int average2 = average[1];
public int average3 = average[2];
```

Hope i helped :)
Edit: Whoops forgot to put a semicolon xD

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to compute the average of several integers in your grades array, as is implied by the name of your method, and regardless of how many items are in the array, you can use Java 8 streams. Just a suggestion.

```
public int average(int[] grades)
{
    OptionalDouble od =  Arrays.stream(grades).average();
    if(od.isPresent())
    {
        return (int)od.getAsDouble();
    }
    return 0; //error condition to be checked by calling method.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the data is in an `array`, you already have "n" individual `int`s.  Each element of the array is an individual `int` that you can access via an index value ranging from 0 to (n - 1), where n is the length of the array.

So an array of 3 `int`s would have indices 0, 1, 2.

With that, if your `average()` is to compute the average of the `int`s you have in your `array`, just loop through your array and accumulate the values into a sum and divide that sum by the number of `int`s that you have.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Average: " + average(new int[] {80, 90, 100}));
}

public static int average(int[] grades) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        sum += grades[i];
    }
    return sum / grades.length;
}
```

Results:

> Average: 90